# Visual Basic Error Generating Folder SHA256 Hash

Tags: vb.net, hash

I want to generate a single SHA256 hash of all the files in a folder in visual basic. I have tried the following code but it generates individual hashes of all files inside the folder, but not a single hash. Can anybody please help.

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim directory As String
        If TextBox2.Text.Length < 1 Then
            Dim fdb As New FolderBrowserDialog
            Dim dr As DialogResult = fdb.ShowDialog()
            If (dr = DialogResult.OK) Then
                directory = fdb.SelectedPath
            Else
                MsgBox("No directory selected")
                Return
            End If
        Else
            directory = TextBox2.Text
        End If
        Try
            ' Create a DirectoryInfo object representing the specified directory. 
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(directory)
            ' Get the FileInfo objects for every file in the directory. 
            Dim files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()
            ' Initialize a SHA256 hash object. 
            Dim mySHA256 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
            Dim hashValue() As Byte
            ' Compute and print the hash values for each file in directory. 
            Dim fInfo As FileInfo
            For Each fInfo In files
                ' Create a fileStream for the file. 
                Dim fileStream As FileStream = fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open)
                ' Be sure it's positioned to the beginning of the stream.
                fileStream.Position = 0
                ' Compute the hash of the fileStream.
                hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(fileStream)
                ' Write the name of the file to the Console.
                MsgBox(fInfo.Name + ": ")
                ' Write the hash value to the Console.
                PrintByteArray(hashValue)
                ' Close the file.
                fileStream.Close()
            Next fInfo
            Return
        Catch DExc As DirectoryNotFoundException
            MsgBox("Error: The directory specified could not be found.")
        Catch IOExc As IOException
            MsgBox("Error: A file in the directory could not be accessed.")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Function PrintByteArray(ByVal array() As Byte)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
            Label3.Text = (String.Format("{0:X2}", array(i)))
            If i Mod 4 = 3 Then
                Label3.Text = (" ")
            End If
        Next i
        Return Label3.Text

    End Function 'PrintByteArray
```

Comment: look at this for inspiration (C# but should be understandable enough if you only know VB to work out an approach) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625658/creating-hash-for-folder/15683147#15683147 . Or, the simplest approach is to containerise (if that is a word - i.e. stick them in a container file like a tarball or uncompressed zip) then hash the container

Comment: also dont label the question as generating an error if it is actually not an error just not doing what you wanted (I presume you copied the code from somewhere) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the hashes with XOR to give one 256-bit hash (32 bytes). Because XOR is associative (A XOR B = B XOR A), it does not matter in which order you XOR the file hashes together. You will have to XOR the individual bytes of each hash: [Most efficient way to xor byte array in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427602/1115360).